# Download file via vbs

Tags: vbscript

I know this has been asked and answered, it is where I found the code to start my project.  But it doesn't work.

I'm stuck.  I have tried and tried and the code(s) don't work.

```
Dim xHttp: Set xHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
Dim bStrm: Set bStrm = CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
xHttp.Open "GET", "https://filexxx.exe", False
xHttp.Send

With bStrm
    .Type = 1 'binary
    .Open
    .Write xHttp.ResponseBody 'this part removed, error, tools not yet avail
    .SaveToFile "c:\temp\xxx.exe", 2 'overwrite
End With
```

And this one.

```
strFileURL = "https://filexxx.exe"
strHDLocation = "C:\temp\xxx.exe"

Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

objXMLHTTP.Open "GET", strFileURL, False
objXMLHTTP.Send()

Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objADOStream.Open
objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary

objADOStream.SaveToFile strHDLocation
```

And this one.

```
strFileURL = "https://filexxx.exe"
strHDLocation = "C:\temp\filexxx.exe"
proxy = null
Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
Set objUserVariables = wshShell.Environment("USER")

'http proxy is optional
'attempt to read from HTTP_PROXY env var first
On Error Resume Next

If Not (objUserVariables("HTTP_PROXY") = "") Then
    proxy = objUserVariables("HTTP_PROXY")
ElseIf Not (WScript.Arguments.Named("proxy") = "") Then
    proxy = WScript.Arguments.Named("proxy")
End If

If Not isNull(proxy) Then
    Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    objXMLHTTP.SetProxy 2, proxy
End If

On Error Goto 0

objXMLHTTP.Open "GET", strFileURL, False
objXMLHTTP.Send()
Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objADOStream.Open
objADOStream.Type = 1
objADOStream.Position = 0
Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFSO.Fileexists(path) Then objFSO.DeleteFile path
Set objFSO = Nothing
objADOStream.SaveToFile strHDLocation
objADOStream.Close
Set objADOStream = Nothing
Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
```

And this one

```
HTTPDownload "https:filexxx.exe", "C:\temp\filexxx.exe"

Sub HTTPDownload(myURL, myPath)
    ' Standard housekeeping
    Dim i, objFile, objFSO, objHTTP, strFile, strMsg
    Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8

    ' Create a File System Object
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    ' Check if the specified target file or folder exists,
    ' and build the fully qualified path of the target file
    If objFSO.FolderExists(myPath) Then
        strFile = objFSO.BuildPath(myPath, Mid(myURL, InStrRev(myURL, "/") + 1))
    ElseIf objFSO.FolderExists(Left(myPath, InStrRev(myPath, "\") - 1)) Then
        strFile = myPath
    Else
        WScript.Echo "ERROR: Target folder not found."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Create or open the target file
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile, ForWriting, True)

    ' Create an HTTP object
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    ' Download the specified URL
    objHTTP.Open "GET", myURL, False
    objHTTP.Send

    ' Write the downloaded byte stream to the target file
    For i = 1 To LenB(objHTTP.ResponseBody)
        objFile.Write Chr(AscB(MidB(objHTTP.ResponseBody, i, 1)))
    Next

    ' Close the target file
    objFile.Close()
End Sub
```

All have same result.  They don't download the file.  Sometimes one of them freezes the computer and I have to manually power down.

They do, after time, download (but don't) and only shows file as 0kb. If I change

```
objXMLHTTP.Open "GET", strFileURL, False
```

to

```
objXMLHTTP.Open "GET", strFileURL, True
```

It instantly shows up in folder and shows 0kb

Either True or False, waiting 30+ minutes does nothing to size of file.  The actual file size is 1,874,886 kB and only takes a couple minutes to download from website.

```
Dim ie
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = False
ie.Navigate2("https://filexxx.exe")
ie.Document.Execwb("saveas", False, "C:\temp\filexxxx.exe")
ie.Quit
```

Gives

> line 5 char 58 cannot use parentheses when calling a sub

And if I remove the quotation marks "" from drive\folder\file I get

> line 5 char 36 expected ")"

Note the URL is https, not http.  Been working on this for couple days now.

Comment: `https://file.exe` is not a valid URL unless there is a webserver hosting a domain `file.exe` from which you want to download the index document. Your first 2 code samples basically do the same. #3 adds proxy handling, which you'd only need if you're actually connecting through a proxy. #2 and #3 can't work, b/c they don't write the response to the stream before saving the file. #4 writes the response byte by byte. #5 makes a [common mistake](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx). I'd expect #1 and #4 to work unless your URL is invalid. Setting the 3rd ... [1/3]

Comment: [2/3] ... parameter of the [`Open`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms757849%28v%3dvs.85%29) method to True is not going to help, b/c that will run the request asynchronously, i.e. the rest of your code will not wait for the request to return a response (which is why you end up with zero-sized files). Forgive me for being blunt here, but throwing random code snippets at a problem without understanding what the code actually does is not going to get you very far. Anyway, like I said: #1 and #2 should have worked AFAICS. If they didn't you need to ... [2/3]

Comment: [3/3] ... provide more information about whatever error you're getting from either of them, as well as a better example for the URL string. Obfuscate the domain (prefereably with an [RFC 2602](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606) domain name) and the file name if you must, but leave the structure of the URL intact.

Comment: I meant "#1 and **#4** shoudl have worked", of course.

Comment: I gave it another shot and went to bed while #4 was running.  Woke next morning to no wifi.  Couldn't turn it on, was worried that I would have to install windows again.  After a few attempts today, with 2 full shutdowns, wifi was working again.  File still didn't download.

Comment: And I put filexxx.exe just to shorten the URL and highlight https.  It is actually https://downloads.website.com/software/downloads/versionnumber/filexxx.exe  (not actual website, just format of the URL)

Comment: And thanks for the format edit.  I forget that vbs is case sensitive unlike cmd.bat files

Comment: VBScript is not case-sensitive. It's just easier to read like that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the point of posting random code is. The point of this code is it says what is happening.

```
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
    Set wshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    Set ShApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    On Error Resume Next
    Set File = WScript.CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    File.Open "GET", "https://www.google.com.au/search?q=cat"), False
    File.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BCD2000; BCD2000)"
    File.Send

        wscript.echo "" 
        wscript.echo "Error getting file" 
        wscript.echo "==================" 
        wscript.echo "" 
        wscript.echo "Error " & err.number & "(0x" & hex(err.number) & ") " & err.description 
        wscript.echo "Source " & err.source 
        wscript.echo "" 
        wscript.echo "HTTP Error " & File.Status & " " & File.StatusText
        wscript.echo    File.getAllResponseHeaders
        wscript.echo    File.ResponseBody

        On Error Goto 0
        wscript.echo "Server Response " & File.Status & " " & File.StatusText
        wscript.echo    File.getAllResponseHeaders
        Set BS = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        BS.type =1
'       BS.Charset = "utf-8"
        BS.open
        BS.Write File.ResponseBody
        BS.Position = 0
        BS.type =2
        BS.Charset = "utf-8"
        wscript.echo    BS.ReadText

        Set BS = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        BS.type = 1
        BS.open
        BS.Write File.ResponseBody
        BS.SaveToFile ShApp.Namespace(&h10).self.path & "\Google.html]", 2
'       wshshell.Run "c:\users\safetyscanner.exe", 1, False
```

Comment: Error line 7 expected end of statement.

Comment: Fixed end of statement.   Turns out I put ) when copying over link.   But don't know where it is saving file to and it froze my PC like other tries posted #1 and #4

Comment: Did it print any messages.

Comment: Yes, line 7 char 111 expected end of statement.  Of course i changed the link from goolge search for cats to my download link of choice.